# Python : _MainThread' object has no attribute '_state'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Hey Guys I am creating an application which takes in a request from the user. The main class in the server side is the Controller . I spawn a thread during init, which keeps actively listening for requests from the client ( I need to spawn a thread here. )

Once I get an request, I look into the type of request and call a function to handle it.

In that function, I want to create multiple processes to utilise my 8 cores effectively.

Here is the code:-

```
class Controller(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS = [ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.datapaths={}
        self.monitor_thread=hub.spawn(self._monitor)
        super(Controller, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

    def _monitor(self):
        global connstream   
        while True:
            #Get Connection from client

            data = connstream.read(15000)
            data=eval(data)
            print "Recieved a request from the client:-",data
            for key,value in data.iteritems():
                type=int(key)
                request=value
                if type==4:
                    self.get_route(type,request,connstream)


    def get_route(self,type,request,connection):
            global get_route_result
            cities=request['Cities']
            number_of_cities=request['Number_of_Cities']
            city_count=0
            processes=[]
            pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
            for city,destination_ip in cities.iteritems():
                 args=(type,destination_ip)
                 processes.append(args)
                 city_count=city_count+1
                 if city_count==number_of_cities:
                      break 
            pool.map(self.get_route_process,processes)  




    def get_route_process(self,HOST,destination):
          #Do Something
```

But the error I get is:-

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in    __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 325, in _handle_workers
while thread._state == RUN or (pool._cache and thread._state != TERMINATE):
AttributeError: '_MainThread' object has no attribute '_state'
```

So in a nutshell, I create a thread, which tries to create multiple processes, but the code fails.

Comment: It's a little hard to see what's failing, since your traceback doesn't really refer to any parts of the program you've shown us.

Comment: @Gerrat the program is failing in the thread which is created during init. This is possibly because I am trying to create multiple process from a thread.

Comment: the monitoring functionality in `Controller` does not seem to use anything from the superlcass. Can't you just spawn two instances, a `monitor` and an instance of `app_manager.RyuApp` (propably with some of your customizations as needed) and pass the instance of the ryuApp to that monitor?

Comment: what/where is `hub` that is referred to in `__init__`, but not shown anywhere?

Comment: @Gerrat hub is from a python module. I am using RYU , which is an openflow controller. Basically i can install rules on switches.

Comment: @tintin that sounds like a good plan. I will be seperating out the monitoring functionality from the class. Probably create an another class and pass the instance of RYU to it. Let me give this a shot.

Comment: This is probably a bug in either `ryu` or python itself.

Comment: In my case a library I use (Nameko) monkey patches standard library to trigger yield when a thread is waiting for IO. If I mix my own threads with nameko I get this error.